# Create a RSS File With a PHP Class

Tags: php, rss, amfphp

I'm having some difficulty getting this script to execute properly.

The create_rss function does not create the RSS file when the remote function updateStatus is called.

```
<?php

define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "user");
define("DB_PASS", "pass");
define("DB_NAME", "db_test");


class updateService
{

     function updateService() 
     {
        $this->methodTable = array(
                "updateStatus" => array(
                    "description" => "Retrieve RSS Info",
                      "arguments" => array("info"),
                         "access" => "remote"
                ),
                 "create_rss" => array(
                    "description" => "Create RSS",
                      "arguments" => array("id"),
                         "access" => "private"                   
                )

     );

     //Connect to MySQL and select database
     $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
     $db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
     }




 /**
 * Update Status
 * @access remote
 */

 //$info contains the integer site id...
 function updateStatus($info)
 {
     create_rss(4);
 }


 function create_rss($id)
 {

 $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?><rss version="2.0">' . "\r\n";
 $xml .= "\t\t" . "<channel>" . "\n\r";
 $xml .= "\t\t\t" . "<title>Website Feed</title>" . "\n\r";
 $xml .= "\t\t\t" . "<link>http://website.com</link>" . "\n\r";
 $xml .= "\t\t\t" . "<description>Website Design</description>" . "\n\r";

 switch ($id)
 {
     case 1:
     $site_name = 'MyTestWebsite';
     $site_link = 'http://www.website.com';
     break;

     case 2:
     $site_name  = 'TestWebsite';
     $link  = 'http://website.com/?q=1&g=2';
     $site_link  = htmlspecialchars($link);
     break; 

     default:
     break; 
 }


 $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE site_id = '$id'
         LIMIT 30";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {

     $timestamp  = $row['timestamp'];

     $xml .= "\t\t" . "<item>" . "\n\r";
     $xml .= "\t\t\t" . "<title>" . $site_name . " Activity</title>" . "\n\r";
     $xml .= "\t\t\t" . "<link>" . $site_link . "</link>" . "\n\r";
     $xml .= "\t\t\t" . '<description><![CDATA[<p><b>Timestamp: ' . $timestamp . '</b></p>]]>' . "\n\r";  
     $xml .= "\t\t" . "</item>" . "\n\r"; 
 }
 $xml .= "\t" . "</channel>" . "\n\r" . "</rss>";


    //create xml file
    $rssfile_path = 'feed/' . $site_name . '.xml';
    chmod($rssfile_path, 0777);

    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $rssfile_path; 
    if (!$file_handle = fopen($file, "w")) 
    { 
        //print "<br>Cannot open XML document:<br>"; 
    }  
    elseif (!fwrite($file_handle, $xml)) 
    { 
        //print "<br>Cannot write to XML document:<br>";   
    }
    else
    {
        //print "<br>Successfully created XML document:<br>";   
    }
    fclose($file_handle);


    }  
}
?>
```

Comment: And how does it not execute properly? I'm not interested in running this code myself, and I am not good enough to parse this in my head.

Comment: tl;dr - I've got better things to do then debug your code for you.

Comment: Tatu, you can't parse this in your head? It's a single function. :) I'm looking for someone with basic knowledge in php classes. I don't understand why this executes outside of a class, but when I call it remotely through flash, nothing happens.

Comment: pygorex, i've got better things to do as well.

Comment: show us the code that's calling it in flash?  So this php script works calling it outside the class?  No bugs there, is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Yeah Tony, I can call this code as a function, and it creates the RSS file. The only thing coming from flash is the $info['site_id'] variable from the remote function. I think the problem lies in the class.

Comment: Make sure that, whenever you say something is failing to execute, you know why. Try using Firebug's Net panel to intercept the request when Flash makes it, so you can see if the request and response are what you'd expect.

Comment: Boil your code down to a problematic snippet, and your problem to something more specific than "it doesn't work".  Lastly, you omitted the code that's actually being called -- surely your flash is invoking a script that creates an instance of this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be mistaken, but I believe that calling a private function "create_rss" from a remote function "updateStatus" does not return anything because of errors generated by the file writing code.

When I separated the code into its own remote function, it returned "undefined". To clean up the code I simply wrote a conditional returning true. Here's a snippet at the end of the code:

```
// SET RSS FILE VARIABLE
//linux    : doc root = dirname
//windows  : doc root = dirname/

$rss_feed_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/feed/';

chmod($rss_feed_dir, 0777);

$file = $rss_feed_dir . $site_name . '.xml';

$file_handle = fopen($file, "w");
fwrite($file_handle, $xml);
fclose($file_handle);

return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to remove the // from the lines with print statements: you have commented out your error messages.
If you have removed them, run the script again.

Comment: I should have deleted the error messages, since they are really not useful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that you left out the constructor. Your function:

```
function updateService() {
....
}
```

Should probably read:

```
function __construct() {
....
}
```

(in php, the constructor does *not* have the same name as its class, use the magic name `__construct` instead)

(BTW - i didn't read all your code, you might get more/bettre responses if you put a bit more effort in formatting it so that it easier to read)

Comment: This came in PHP5, which still supports using the class name as the constructor function, otherwise all PHP4 scripts would just die, and CodeIgniter would never be used.

Comment: @seanmonstar, PHP5 seems so much more organized and clean. No more methodTables. Someone should really update AMFPHP